# kotlin fuel gson Error BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Response from api. How to get data from this result. Use Fuel connect api
 **Error :**

> BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

I don't understand it

```
{    
      "data": {
        "translations": [
          {
            "translatedText": "คุณชอ`enter code here`บฉันไหม คุณชอบใคร? ถึง 12 ML 2. 19. 9. 19 ROADSHOW kiele หัวเราะและร้องไห้และร้องไห้ผิวรักเป็นประวัติการณ์เกิด",
            "detectedSourceLanguage": "ja"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

class Textmodel {
    @SerializedName("translations")
    @Expose
    var translation: List<MessageResult>? = null


    class MessageResult {
        @SerializedName("translatedText")
        @Expose
        var message: String? = null
        @SerializedName("detectedSourceLanguage")
        @Expose
        var originalLanguage: String? = null

        constructor(message: String?, originalLanguage: String?) {
            this.message = message
            this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage
        }

    }

   class ListDeserializer : ResponseDeserializable<List<Textmodel>> {
        override fun deserialize(content: String) =

                Gson().fromJson<List<Textmodel>>(content,object :TypeToken<List<Textmodel>>(){}.type)
    }
```

I want to get data form this object.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your parsing code was expecting to find a BEGIN_ARRAY delimiter (`[`), but it found a BEGIN_OBJECT delimiter (`{`) instead. Essentially, your objects that GSON is attempting to parse are expecting an array in a place where the JSON input is providing on object.

It's a little bit tough to debug with just a small snippet of code, but you want to make sure that the object models you are providing to GSON for deserialization are able to parse the JSON input from the root down to the data you're interested in accessing. My hunch is that you're missing the part that parses the `"data"` object.

Comment: Yes. Do you have example this case.

Comment: There is too much code missing from your example to provide a clear answer here.